# Random movement attempt

Tags: random, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, unityscript

I'm trying to make my bear walk randomly when the player is not in it's range. I wanted it to randomly select the its rotation in y axis and then move it forward and after some time switch the rotation randomly again.

The thing is that I don't really know how could I assign him a random rotation.
So how do I do this?

I finally managed to do this, here's the working code:

```js
var timeToChangeDirection : float = 60;
private var angle : Vector3;

var damping : float = 6.0;

var controller : CharacterController;

function Update()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

    if(distance > aggroRange)
    {
        moveSpeed = 1;
        timeToChangeDirection -= 0.1;

        if (timeToChangeDirection <= 0) 
        {
            ChangeDirection();
        }

        controller.Move(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
        animation["Run"].speed = 0.25;
        animation.Play("Run");
    }

function ChangeDirection()
{
    angle = Vector3(transform.rotation.x, Random.Range(-359, 359), transform.rotation.y);
    transform.Rotate(angle);
    timeToChangeDirection = 60;
}
```

Comment: What is your question about? How to get a random direction?

Comment: Yeah. Gonna edit my post to make it more clear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I've managed to do it after all.
Here's the code if anyone is interested:

```js
var timeToChangeDirection : float = 60;
private var angle : Vector3;

var damping : float = 6.0;

var controller : CharacterController;

function Update()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

    if(distance > aggroRange)
    {
        moveSpeed = 1;
        timeToChangeDirection -= 0.1;

        if (timeToChangeDirection <= 0) 
        {
            ChangeDirection();
        }

        controller.Move(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
        animation["Run"].speed = 0.25;
        animation.Play("Run");
    }

function ChangeDirection()
{
    angle = Vector3(transform.rotation.x, Random.Range(-359, 359), transform.rotation.y);
    transform.Rotate(angle);
    timeToChangeDirection = 60;
}
```

Comment: You should really condense your answer down to only what is needed to resolve your problem.

Comment: Sorry. I'm quite new here and I don't know conventions yet. Thanks for help :)